# Adding variable as a factor to glm

Tags: r, glm, poisson

My dataset has been collected from two different locations. I want to add the locations to my GLM, and got the feedback to add them as a random effect, but I'm not sure how to do that. I have tried the following for now:

```
model = glm(formula = taeni_number ~ 0 + dum_grass + dum_gravel + dum_multi + factor(river), data=data, family=poisson(link="log"))
```

With the dataset:

```
structure(list(dum_grass = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), dum_gravel = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), dum_multi = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), taeni_number = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 8L, 34L, 5L, 11L, 
19L, 7L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 14L, 19L, 10L, 15L, 8L, 3L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 4L, 9L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 15L, 
2L, 2L, 9L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-108L))
```

the river column just indicates which river the data was collected from with either a 1 or 0, and I have added it to the model as a factor. However, it gives the same input as it would when I add the river variable as a dummy, and doesn't compute for the 2nd option because they are directly dependent on eachother.

Does anyone have a solution to this issue? Am i doing the random effect thing entirely wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "random factor" You adviser means a random effect. Inform yourself about mixed-effects models. This book gives an easy introduction: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-87458-6

Comment: The `L`s denote integer numbers in R.